convert a polars.DataFrames of List[Struct[2]] to a dict of polars.DataFrame
I have a single row polars.DataFrame df with schema
df.schema

>>> Schema([('S1',
         List(Struct({'S1': Float64, 'timestamp': Datetime(time_unit='us', time_zone=None)}))),
        ('S2',
         List(Struct({'S2': Float64, 'timestamp': Datetime(time_unit='us', time_zone=None)}))),
        ('S3',
         List(Struct({'S3': Float64, 'timestamp': Datetime(time_unit='us', time_zone=None)}))),
        ('CO',
         List(Struct({'CO': Float64, 'timestamp': Datetime(time_unit='us', time_zone=None)}))),
        ('RH',
         List(Struct({'RH': Float64, 'timestamp': Datetime(time_unit='us', time_zone=None)}))),
        ('TP',
         List(Struct({'TP': Float64, 'timestamp': Datetime(time_unit='us', time_zone=None)})))])

I want to convert it into a dict of polars.DataFrame, currently im using the following technique
{
    c: pl.DataFrame(v.explode()).unnest(c)

    for c,v in df.to_dict().items()
}

which gives me a dictionary with the schema
{'S1': Schema([('S1', Float64),
         ('timestamp', Datetime(time_unit='us', time_zone=None))]),
 'S2': Schema([('S2', Float64),
         ('timestamp', Datetime(time_unit='us', time_zone=None))]),
 'S3': Schema([('S3', Float64),
         ('timestamp', Datetime(time_unit='us', time_zone=None))]),
 'CO': Schema([('CO', Float64),
         ('timestamp', Datetime(time_unit='us', time_zone=None))]),
 'RH': Schema([('RH', Float64),
         ('timestamp', Datetime(time_unit='us', time_zone=None))]),
 'TP': Schema([('TP', Float64),
         ('timestamp', Datetime(time_unit='us', time_zone=None))])}

I cannot use .explode() on the original df because all the list elements in the df are of different lengths. I would like know if there is a more elegant or polarsish syntax of doing it
here is some sample data
import datetime as dt
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame({
    'S1': [[
        {'S1': 102007.4             , 'timestamp': dt.datetime(2024, 9, 4, 14, 58, 37)},
        {'S1': 102007.45454545454   , 'timestamp': dt.datetime(2024, 9, 4, 14, 58, 54)},
        {'S1': 102005.83333333333   , 'timestamp': dt.datetime(2024, 9, 4, 14, 59, 11)},
        {'S1': 102000.07692307692   , 'timestamp': dt.datetime(2024, 9, 4, 14, 59, 28)},
        {'S1': 101996.0             , 'timestamp': dt.datetime(2024, 9, 4, 15, 0 , 1 )},
    ]],
    'S2': [[
        {'S2': 50902.6              , 'timestamp': dt.datetime(2024, 9, 4, 14, 58, 37)},
        {'S2': 50904.09090909091    , 'timestamp': dt.datetime(2024, 9, 4, 14, 58, 54)},
        {'S2': 50904.833333333336   , 'timestamp': dt.datetime(2024, 9, 4, 14, 59, 11)},
        {'S2': 50903.0              , 'timestamp': dt.datetime(2024, 9, 4, 14, 59, 28)},
    ]],
    'S3': [[
        {'S3': 860903.6666666666    , 'timestamp': dt.datetime(2024, 9, 4, 14, 58, 20)},
        {'S3': 860899.4545454546    , 'timestamp': dt.datetime(2024, 9, 4, 14, 58, 54)},
        {'S3': 860862.5833333334    , 'timestamp': dt.datetime(2024, 9, 4, 14, 59, 11)},
    ]],
    'CO': [[
        {'CO': 639162.2             , 'timestamp': dt.datetime(2024, 9, 4, 14, 58, 37)},
        {'CO': 639161.2727272727    , 'timestamp': dt.datetime(2024, 9, 4, 14, 58, 54)},
        {'CO': 639159.4166666666    , 'timestamp': dt.datetime(2024, 9, 4, 14, 59, 11)},
        {'CO': 639167.5             , 'timestamp': dt.datetime(2024, 9, 4, 14, 59, 44)},
        {'CO': 639163.2666666667    , 'timestamp': dt.datetime(2024, 9, 4, 15,  0,  1)},
    ]],
    'RH': [[
        {'RH': 3655.3               , 'timestamp': dt.datetime(2024, 9, 4, 14, 58, 37)},
        {'RH': 3655.2727272727275   , 'timestamp': dt.datetime(2024, 9, 4, 14, 58, 54)},
    ]],
    'TP': [[
        {'TP': 2621.7               , 'timestamp': dt.datetime(2024, 9, 4, 14, 58, 37)},
        {'TP': 2621.818181818182    , 'timestamp': dt.datetime(2024, 9, 4, 14, 58, 54)},
    ]],
})



Are you saying the current technique works? You just want a nicer way? What you have looks equivalent to { s.name: s.list.explode().struct.unnest() for s in df } - if this is what you're asking for?

Since you need to explode each of these separately, you will need to manually
iterate over the columns. Since these queries produce independent results
from one another, I would also parallelize this work via a LazyFrame and using
pl.collect_all:
ldf = df.lazy()
names = ldf.collect_schema().names()
expressions = [
    ldf.select(pl.col(n).explode().struct.field('*')) for n in names
]
df_dict = dict(zip(names, pl.collect_all(expressions)))

from pprint import pprint
pprint(df_dict)
# {'CO': shape: (5, 2)
# ┌───────────────┬─────────────────────┐
# │ CO            ┆ timestamp           │
# │ ---           ┆ ---                 │
# │ f64           ┆ datetime[μs]        │
# ╞═══════════════╪═════════════════════╡
# │ 639162.2      ┆ 2024-09-04 14:58:37 │
# │ 639161.272727 ┆ 2024-09-04 14:58:54 │
# │ 639159.416667 ┆ 2024-09-04 14:59:11 │
# │ 639167.5      ┆ 2024-09-04 14:59:44 │
# │ 639163.266667 ┆ 2024-09-04 15:00:01 │
# └───────────────┴─────────────────────┘,
# ...
# }

